# Sign in with goggle button not displayed

Tags: angular, typescript, button, google-signin

I followed the google documentation to setup sign in and sign up with google in my angular application. I created my project and generated my cliend_id succesfully, I generated the button code using google console, however the button "sign in with google" is not displaying.

this is the script that I put in my index.html

```
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>
```

and this is the button code that I put in my component.

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="My_client_id"
     data-context="signup"
     data-ux_mode="popup"
     data-itp_support="true"
    data-callback="handleCredentialResponsekk">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
```

I'm using chrome to test my app, I change to edge, I can see the button sometimes but not always. can you help me please.

Comment: Remove the `<script>` element from your static HTML and instead only add the `<script>` element to the DOM _after_ your Component (with `<div id="g_id_onload"`) has fully loaded. If you can guarantee that your Component will always be loaded _before_ `DOMContentLoaded` then you can keep your existing `<script>` but change the `async` attribute to `defer`.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot, I added the script to my component. do you know how to call another function in my .ts unstead of calling handleCredentialResponsekk?

Comment: You haven't posted any TypeScript code.

Comment: I want to move these two function from the index.html to my component   

`<script>
    function decodeJWTToken(token) {
      return JSON.parse(atob(token.split(".")[1]));
    }
    function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
      // to decode the credential response.
      const responsePayload = decodeJWTToken(response.credential);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(responsePayload))
      sessionStorage.setItem("loggedInUser", JSON.stringify(responsePayload));
      window.location.href = "/dashboard";
    }
  </script>`

Comment: Clients have no need or reason to ever attempt to decode a JWT `access_token`... If you want user-claims use the `id_token`: https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/